# Why do Isolation Forest implementations turn it into a supervised learning problem (with random values for the target?)

Tags: python, r, isolation-forest

I am looking at various implementations of the Isolation Forest in python and R.
Both sklearn in python and solitude in R use a y variable with the ExtraTrees regressor.

Since, Isolation Forest is unsupervised, I am wondering why it is being turned into a supervised problem? Wouldnt this be an issue when scoring on previously unseen data sets?

For example sklearn (python) [line 248](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a675319e93b9c51e9779ec65922ec30539fb98d3/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py#L248) has this.

And in solitude [line 144](https://github.com/talegari/solitude/blob/b76ff146d3e74584a9c640e4f9ca4b67f290aba2/R/isolationForest_r6.R#L144) as well.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/isolation-forest-from-scratch-e7e5978e6f4c

Answer (score 3):

Extra-random Trees needs a target variable, so Isolation Forest generates a random target ([sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/74b632a1aa880a9c7f855599d16603626edf97fa/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py#L248), [solitude](https://github.com/talegari/solitude/blob/e216f7d429c5c1173726e6bfc5859f6a868d1426/R/isolationForest_r6.R#L158)).  At prediction time, no `y` values are used, and the ExtraTrees doesn't actually make a prediction; instead, the samples are propagated to the leaves and the depth is extracted ([sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/74b632a1aa880a9c7f855599d16603626edf97fa/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py#L437)).

As for the tree-building process, sklearn at least doesn't make use of the `y` values, because the ExtraTrees model has `max_features=1` and `splitter='random'` ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/74b632a1aa880a9c7f855599d16603626edf97fa/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py#L192)).  I'm not so sure about `solitude`, since it has `mtry=ncol-1` ([source](https://github.com/talegari/solitude/blob/e216f7d429c5c1173726e6bfc5859f6a868d1426/R/isolationForest_r6.R#L177)); maybe further down, using `splitrule='extratrees'` takes care of that?  Otherwise, the splits chosen will try to optimize on the random `y`, though since those are random it maybe doesn't matter (certainly I wouldn't call it a supervised model, anyway).

Comment: The key point here is that the trees aren't actually used to make a prediction - only the partitioning of examples across the tree (i.e. the "depth" of each sample) is used.